# Does a hallway to a walk-in closet need to meet width requirements?

Tags: code-compliance, closet

I am putting up two new walls (highlighted in green below) to make room for a walk in closet. The hallway established for access to this closet is not going to be a minimum of 36" wide.

Do I need to locate the doorway on the side of the room facing the furniture? Thanks.

[image: diagram]

I am located in Brick, NJ. Zip is 08723

Comment: I don't think there is any real egress issue for a closet. But what are you going to do with the 27" x 76" little section? About the only ways I can see making use of it are (a) storage, in which case why not make it part of the closet or (b) a little built-in desk at the end (i.e., bottom of the image) which if you made it only ~ 18" - 20" deep would work OK except that nobody could get in/out of the closet easily when someone is sitting at the desk.

Comment: IDK, maybe the OP doesn't want to be able to see the closet door from the room?  I agree; the 27x76 area seems like wasted space—I'd just expand the closet to fill that space too.

Comment: We can't frame it that way. It'll run into a window, but I think we can run it in a zig zag and take advantage of a ceiling joist. Ceiling joists are perpendicular to the window and spaced 24" OC

Comment: It's a good question--technically the hallway is your only escape from the closet. I think I'd find another layout rather than creating an 18th century arrangement, though. A smaller walk-in along with a conventional closet at the other end might do. That said, a 27" opening is actually _more_ than a 2-4 (28") doorway would give you.

Comment: I tend to agree that closing off the entire area and putting a door on the face makes more sense unless something is going on that we haven't been told. Not only does the corridor seem wasteful unless it actually leads somewhere, I suspect that if you or a future buyer are ever dealing with a wheelchair you'll curse whoever decided to create that narrow access.

Comment: Where is the window?  Can you add it to your diagram?   You're spending a lot of money and effort on a "walk in closet" that, after adding storage, will have a tiny open area just big enough to stand in.  More of a dressing chamber than a walk-in.  And the new corridor requires lighting, cleaning and gives nothing back.  From the bedroom it will look like an ugly mistake.  Hopefully you can do better, let's see the window?

Comment: Added window to the diagram

Comment: Instead of that 63" wall (running up-and-down in the diagram), put in a left-to-right wall ending at the right hand side. Turns that difficult-to-use space at the end of the hallway into part of the closet. And maybe put the door into that wall.

Comment: @PeteBecker it may be preferable to put the door as shown in the diagram because the daylight from the window can enter the closet

Comment: Ok, with the window!  You have a large bedroom with a large window, and the ability to create a beautiful space.  Instead you are creating a smaller bedroom that will be dominated by the bed and feel cramped, a "walk in" that is more of a small storage chamber, and a useless passage to nowhere.  Instead, **forget about the walk in**.  What you do next is up to you but .... [1/2]

Comment: [ 2/2] here is a suggestion: Put a custom closet or a closet solution such as IKEA PAX along the entire 76 and 79 inch walls. (S and SW).  Put a sofa under the window for dressing, reading, etc.  You end up with more storage than your walk-in, a bedroom the still feels large and airy, a *large* open well-lit space for dressing, stretching, etc and a seating area for reading, dressing, and more.   This will add value to your house.  Your walk-in will do the opposite.

Comment: @jay613 adding furniture wouldn't add value to the house. The bedroom is not a bedroom without a closet. But I do appreciate the insight. I'll look into the PAX options and am considering a square area running the entire 106" * 60".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instead the closet could take the entire 79+27 width, but be only 63 deep as that's what's available beside the window, you would net 10% *more* floor area inside the closet. (63 * (79+27) = 6678 sq in, compare to 76 * 79 = 6004 sq in)

It routinely happens in commercial office renovations that a wall is wanted in a location that would intersect with a window. They just go ahead and build it there, window not withstanding. The end of the wall near the window gets some metal, like a corner bead, which covers the rough drywall edges that would otherwise be visible near the glass. Depending on your tastes and the division of the window into panes, there might be a way for you to follow this strategy.

Comment: Ew.  No downvote because it's factual. But ew.

Comment: Need to black out the closet half.

Comment: @isherwood That's true, it's not a direct answer. More of an X-Y challenge. I hesitated to even post it. But a recent comment on the question indicates the challenge offered in the first paragraph is at least under consideration by OP. Maybe it's worthwhile to let this pseudo-answer stand.

Answer (score 3):

Whether it's a good idea is off topic. The IRC R311.6 commentary states that

> Hallways must be a minimum of 3 feet (914 mm) wide to accommodate moving furniture into rooms off the hallway and for safe egress from the structure.

Since furniture presumably isn't an issue for a closet and egress from a closet isn't an issue, then no, the "hallway" doesn't need to meet the 36" requirement. Of course your AHJ will have the final say.

Strike the word "hallway" from your vocabulary. That's "closet access" or a "closet entry."

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I've altered my plans and this question has been superceded by [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/289432/are-there-any-safety-or-code-concerns-with-my-closet-design?noredirect=1&lq=1)